# How Dyanamics of car model is encorporated in webots

Tags: webots

I am trying to control the car in webots using some control laws from literature. I want know that how dynamics of car are incorporated in webots for various car models......?

Comment: Cars in Webots rely on the Ackermann model, see details here: https://cyberbotics.com/doc/automobile/ackermannvehicle

Comment: If we use a kinematic control scheme for trajectory tracking purposes in webots platform. Is it feasible.....?

Comment: Yes, it should work.